# Is there a way to retrieve the latest of the first `status` value from the table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been trying to write a query that returns the `latest` of the first status matching record with the query itself. Let's say I have the table records below, I would like to retrieve the `APP_ID` and the `INSERTED_AT` columns where the `STATUS` should be the first of `Offer Sent` that occurs after the latest `Selectable` status and if there are any `Offer Declined` should ignore it.

| ID | APP_ID | INSERTED_AT | UPDATED_AT | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 209377 | 2021-05-13 20:57:30.000 +0530 | 2021-05-13 20:57:30.000 +0530 | Selectable |
| 2 | 209377 | 2021-05-13 20:57:58.000 +0530 | 2021-05-13 20:57:58.000 +0530 | Selectable |
| 3 | 209377 | 2021-05-14 18:40:08.000 +0530 | 2021-05-14 18:40:08.000 +0530 | Offer Eligible |
| 4 | 209377 | 2021-05-14 18:40:14.000 +0530 | 2021-05-14 18:40:14.000 +0530 | Offer Sent |
| 5 | 209377 | 2021-05-15 18:57:50.000 +0530 | 2021-05-15 18:57:50.000 +0530 | Offer Sent |
| 6 | 209377 | 2021-05-15 20:44:29.000 +0530 | 2021-05-15 20:44:29.000 +0530 | Offer Sent |
| 7 | 209377 | 2021-05-17 22:45:13.000 +0530 | 2021-05-17 22:45:13.000 +0530 | Offer Accepted |
| 8 | 110011 | 2021-05-13 20:57:30.000 +0530 | 2021-05-13 20:57:30.000 +0530 | Selectable |
| 9 | 110011 | 2021-05-13 20:57:58.000 +0530 | 2021-05-13 20:57:58.000 +0530 | Offer Eligible |
| 10 | 110011 | 2021-06-14 18:40:08.000 +0530 | 2021-05-14 18:40:08.000 +0530 | Offer Sent |
| 11 | 300110 | 2021-05-14 18:40:14.000 +0530 | 2021-05-14 18:40:14.000 +0530 | Selectable |
| 12 | 300110 | 2021-05-15 18:57:50.000 +0530 | 2021-05-15 18:57:50.000 +0530 | Offer Eligible |
| 13 | 300110 | 2021-05-15 20:44:29.000 +0530 | 2021-05-15 20:44:29.000 +0530 | Offer Sent |
| 14 | 300110 | 2021-05-17 22:45:13.000 +0530 | 2021-05-17 22:45:13.000 +0530 | Offer Declined |

Here are the expected results I am looking for

| APP_ID | INSERTED_AT | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 209377 | 2021-05-14 18:40:14.000 +0530 | Offer Sent |
| 110011 | 2021-05-14 18:40:08.000 +0530 | Offer Sent |
| 300110 | nil | Offer Declined |

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Select *, max(case when status ='Selected' then
     When lag(status) over (order by 
     null) ='Offer Sent' then 'Offer Sent' 
     Else nil end) 
   From
   (
   Select APP_ID, INSERTED_AT,  
   Status 
    From table
    Where status in ('Selected', 'Offer Sent', 'Offer 
     Declined'))
```